# Resetting Odd/Even Sequence in HTML Table

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I fear the answer is no, but just wanted to try and confirm.

I am setting every other row of a table to have a gray background.

```
table tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

This works fine, but there are also embedded header rows within the table. And I would like the odd/even pattern to reset and start again following each header row.

What I would really like is a style I could assign to my header rows to indicate the row numbers should start again at 1 on the next row.

Is there any CSS styling to specify that the odd/even row tracking should be reset this way?

*Note: I know I could turn to jQuery or adding custom classes to rows in my table. I was just hoping for a CSS-only solution.*

**EDIT:**

Some have requested that I should how the table it laid out. So I'll do that here. I don't understand how this helps as a table is pretty basic and I thought it was obvious that all rows were siblings of each other.

```
<table>
    <tr class="SectionHeader">
        <th>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="SectionHeader">
        <th>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="SectionHeader">
        <th>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML code with the embedded row?

Comment: Yes its possible, by using the sibling css3 selector. Table decendant of Table first row, apply x style. The syntax is blurry to me but I have done this before... and it works with `n` amount of embedded tables. But you also have to work in reverse in the CSS, I think. Well any way, it is possbile.

Comment: @ManojKumar: It's just a `<tr>` element. I can populate it with either `<td>`s or `<th>`s.

Comment: @ppumkin: So what am I searching for to do this?

Comment: CSS3 siblings, decendant, selectors. They use the syntax simlar to `table > table :nth row` something like that

Comment: Multiple header rows? Why don't you use multiple tables?

Comment: Show what your DOM is laid out like.

Comment: @klenium: Because then extra work is required to make all the columns line up.

Comment: @Nit: Can you give me any example at all to help me understand how showing the DOM layout would clarify this question? It's a table. Other people seem to understand what I'm asking. Please help me understand how the DOM layout would clarify things.

Comment: @ppumkin: If you remember any more details, please let me know. The count would need to reset to 1, meaning that the row after that would be considered 2. I can't see how I can use sibling or descendant selectors to accomplish that.

Comment: Of interest are the embedded header rows that you mention. What does the HTML for these rows look like? Are these nested table elements, or thead elements, or some other complex structure? This is best represented and visualized with some example markup, or ideally (but optionally) a fiddle, in particular because CSS selectors are very sensitive to HTML structure.

Comment: You need to work with odd an even selectors in CSS not using counters, so to speak. `table tr:nth-child(even)` and then embedded `table > table tr:nth-child(even)` - that is just psuedo code, but essentially thats how you control the embedded tables css.

Comment: Use multiple `tbody` elements. The you can do `tbody > tr:nth-child(even)`.

Comment: "I thought it was obvious that all rows were siblings of each other" Rows can be grouped into elements such as thead, tfoot and tbody, which is why I generally avoid making that assumption.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest you can get to dynamic values in CSS is with counters, but counters can't be used with selectors. A selector is mostly static with the exception of dynamic pseudo-classes. You can't use CSS to set an arbitrary value that will affect how a selector matches elements.

As suggested in the comments, your table structure is better represented using multiple `tbody` elements, one for each section. This would *also* allow your existing `:nth-child()` selector to match the correct row elements:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="SectionHeader">
      <th scope="rowgroup">
    <tr>
      <td>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="SectionHeader">
      <th scope="rowgroup">
    <tr>
      <td>
    <tr>
      <td>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="SectionHeader">
      <th scope="rowgroup">
    <tr>
      <td>
    <tr>
      <td>
</table>
```

- end tags omitted to keep things clean; FYI this is perfectly valid HTML
- I kept the "SectionHeader" class name from your original markup, but note that the `scope="rowgroup"` attribute on each header cell provides the appropriate semantics where a class name does not

Comment: I don't understand the `scope="rowgroup"` attribute. What is the purpose of that?

Comment: Also, searching around, I read that `The <td> scope attribute is not supported in HTML5.`

Comment: @Jonathan Wood: It's basically the same thing as `class="SectionHeader"`, except with defined meaning in HTML. The "rowgroup" in this case refers to its parent tbody. That statement appears to be coming from W3Schools, and it's a strange statement because the scope attribute has never ever applied to `td` in any version of HTML, it only applies to `th` elements, so the question of "support" would be irrelevant there. They probably meant to say "The scope attribute does not apply to <td> elements."

Comment: @BoltClock Wait a minute. [This page](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#edef-TD), the official, definitive W3C reference on tables in HTML 4.01, says that `scope` is defined on `td` cells. _"You should use the `TD` element for such cells together with the `id` or `scope` attributes as appropriate."_

Comment: @Mr Lister: wat. That's ridiculous. But then again, that's HTML 4. I stand corrected. I see that the DTD basically groups th and td with the same ATTLIST as well.

Comment: @BoltClock There is also [this page](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/td.html) about HTML5, also by the W3C. that says _"The scope attribute on the td element is obsolete. Use the scope attribute on a th element instead."_ again confirming that `<td scope>` was once correct.

Answer (score 3):

Since you didn't demonstrate a DOM, I'm going to offer a solution that relies on a specific DOM structure:

If you can use `<thead>` and `<tbody>` elements, the issue becomes trivial.

```css
tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Header element</th>
    <th>Header element</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jane</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jane</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tr>
    <th>Header element</th>
    <th>Header element</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Longer Than The Usual John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jane</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is incorrect. Tables can contain only one `thead`. Also, the OP posted their DOM half a minute before you posted your answer.

Comment: @Mr Lister: Don't you hate it when that happens.

Comment: @MrLister Depending on how the document is generated, it might be a viable answer regardless. But at least it goes to demonstrate why including your markup is important.

Comment: Well, this isn't the answer I was hoping for because it requires every table using these styles (which could be a lot) to be formatted a particular way. But perhaps it is the best answer.

Comment: @MrLister Good catch, I rarely work with tables so that completely slipped past my guard. Still, the concept is the same. Expanding on your point though, I'm not sure if my edit is standards compliant.

Answer (score 2):

Since the consensus seems to be that it can't be done with CSS alone without changing the layout of the table, I couldn't help but rise to the challenge, so here it is.

```css
tr.SectionHeader,
tr.SectionHeader + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader),
tr.SectionHeader + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader),
tr.SectionHeader + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader),
tr.SectionHeader + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader),
tr.SectionHeader + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader),
tr.SectionHeader + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader),
tr.SectionHeader + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader) + tr:not(.SectionHeader) {
  background:#EEE}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr class="SectionHeader">
        <th>hdr
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="SectionHeader">
        <th>hdr
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>cell
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="SectionHeader">
        <th>hdr
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>cell
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>cell
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="SectionHeader">
        <th>hdr
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>cell
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>cell
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>cell
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="SectionHeader">
        <th>hdr
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>cell
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>cell
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>cell
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>cell
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

(Works with sequences of up to 14 non-header rows. If you need more, just add more CSS.)

Comment: Well, +1 for the attempt. :) This is pretty unsightly though, and if I'm not mistaken, it breaks down if I have too many consecutive regular rows.

Comment: Yeah, but you can add more CSS if needed. Seriously now, sorry, but you really should to the tbody thing.

Comment: Yes, looking into the `<tbody>` options now. (Turns out they are problematic in WebForms.) But I have no idea how many consecutive regular rows I will have.

Comment: This is why I try to be careful not to make such sweeping statements as "it can't be done with CSS alone" anymore and just be specific as to what exactly cannot be done, or the limitations of potential CSS solutions.

Comment: @JonathanWood WebForms you say? Aw. I feel your pain.